# How to return child object names along with parent details in django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have two models Destination and Cruise

```
#Models
class Destination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique= True, null= False, blank=False, max_length= 50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length= 2000, null= False, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
          return self.name

class Cruise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique= True, null= False, blank=False, max_length= 50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length= 2000, null= False, blank=False)
    destinations = models.ForeignKey("Destination", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Im trying to show the Destination details along with all the Cruises under that destination.

```
#Views
class DestinationDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'destination_detail.html'
    queryset = models.Destination.objects.all()
       
    context_object_name = "destination"
```

HTML

```
#html
{% block content %}

Destination Name = {{destination.name}}
Description = {{destination.description}}
Cruise = {{destination.cruises}}

{% blockend content %}
```

Please advise how to print all cruises under perticual destination.

Comment: Cruise = {{destination.cruise_set.all}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem by adding for loop in HTML.

#html

```
{% block content %}

Destination Name = {{destination.name}}
Description = {{destination.description}}
Cruise = 
{% for cruise in destination.cruises.all %}
{{ cruise.name }} </br>
{% endfor %}

{% blockend content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want to display the contents of some cruise fields in you html.

You can use the `for` template tag as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for), e.g.:

```
#html
{% block content %}

Destination Name = {{destination.name}}
Description = {{destination.description}}
Cruise = 
{% for cruise in destination.cruise_set.all %}
{{ cruise.name }} </br>
{% endfor %}

{% blockend content %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Small changes helped to fix it.